# Export selected rows in CSV and import back same CSV file to update selected rows in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a mysql table with following columns:

```
filterid    productid   value   groupid
```

I want to export the rows of this table (Only selected rows) to a CSV file.
I know how to do the exporting part.

For example, if I have exported the rows based on product ID, let say exported rows are:

```
4   13307   USA|Quebec|Rest of Canada   750
9   15963   USA|Quebec|Rest of Canada   1
9   13618   USA|Quebec|Rest of Canada   1
9   16210   USA|Quebec|Rest of Canada   1
9   16666   USA|Quebec|Rest of Canada   1
```

Out of total 100 rows.

Now, I have exported this content into a CSV file and want to import it back to my mysql table where it should update only rows matching with the product id's which are in my exported CSV file without disturbing rest of the table content.

Is it possible to do that?

After googling, what I found is that I can import a CSV to a table using this code

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'filename.csv' INTO TABLE my_table FIELDS
TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Please suggest a way to achieve this.

I can provide you with more sample code if you need.

Thank You!

Comment: You already found the CSV import function [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html). What's not working about it?

Comment: @Groundshaker If you post good questions/answers, people won't downvote them. Asking people not to downvote doesn't make them less likely to, in fact, it may make them more likely to downvote, at least it makes me want to. P.S. I'm not planning on downvoting your question.

Comment: So using PHP is OK right?  I have a script I literally just wrote that will parse CSV files..

Comment: @Mario: I was not familiar with its WHERE clause. Following example by burmat seems perfect and I'm going to try that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think he was asking the question because he didn't know how to use `INFILE` with a `WHERE` clause:

> Now, I have exported this content into a CSV file and want to import
>   it back to my mysql table where it **should update only rows matching
>   with the product id's** which are in my exported CSV file without
>   disturbing rest of the table content.

If you want to use a script to do what you mentioned, you can try the following:

```
// set up your database connection
$fp = fopen('your_csv_file.csv','r') or die("**! can't open file\n\n");

// loop through your lines
while($csv_line = fgetcsv($fp,1024)) {

    $filterid = $csv_line[0];
    $productid = $csv_line[1];
    $value = $csv_line[2];
    $groupid = $csv_line[3];

    $update =  "UPDATE your_table(filterid, productid, value, groupid) ";
    $update .= "VALUES('$filterid', '$productid'; '$value'; '$goupid') WHERE productid='$productid'";

    // run $update on your database
}

fclose($fp) or die("**! can't close file\n\n");
```

It should at least point you in the right direction..

Comment: Great one!!

Let me test it on my localhost and then will revert back to you!

Thank You!